# AngularJS - how to focus on an element via a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I know the question has been asked multiple time, but I can't seem to find anywhere how to focus to an element from within a controller. What is the best approach? Would it be better to do a directive? But if so, then how would I call it within my controller? Or is it better to create a service then? 

What I already have and works properly from within HTML code is a directive:

```
.directive('ngxFocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        $timeout(function () { 
            element.focus();
         }, 10);
      };    
}])
```

Can I call directive within controller? I'm still learning AngularJS and I'm a bit confused on what the best approach is in this case. I really want to do it via the controller, at the moment I use a simple 1 line of jQuery to focus, but yeah it's not the Angular way and so I'd like to go with the correct way.

**Note**
To be more specific with an example, let say I have 10 inputs in the HTML and let say that inside the execution of a function (defined in the controller), I want to focus on 1 of the multiple inputs directly from the function (again this is all declared inside the controller). I would rather not write anything inside the HTML code, if possible, but instead call a focus function or something that will focus to the input I chose. I know I could write it simply in jQuery with `$('input12').focus();` but I want to know how to do it the AngularJS way. All the answers I get so far are based on writing a Directive, that also equals to writing something inside the HTML, isn't there any other way??? 

**Example**
For more explicit example of my form... I have a first input connected to a Yahoo web service (stock market), this input filled by the user will hold a stock quotes symbol that can be anywhere in the world and then the user will choose (from a dropdown) his Bank account... now from there, my controller will check that the stock quotes market is in the same currency as the user's bank account (ex.: GOOG is US currency, if user's account is in $CAD, it will fail because GOOG is in $USD). If currency isn't the same, I want to advise my user and to do so I would seriously prefer to focus on the field so he could change his symbol if he made an error.

Comment: I think you will not find solution shorter than using one line of jquery. You always have to use selectors, no matter if you create service or do it straight from controller, because you always need to select an element you want to manipulate.

Comment: Yes I know that jQuery is shorter, but I believe it is not the proper way to do it. I'm looking for that proper Angular way...

Comment: Ok, so check the solution I've posted below. Maybe it will satisfy you ;)

Answer (score 2):

I you're trying to work with elements in controller, be sure you're going wrong, the controller's target in to bind data received from services to view, not to manipulate view.
If you want to focus on an element with route change:

```
app.directive('focuser', ['$location', function ($location) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element) {
      $scope.$watch(function () {
        //simply focus
        $element.focus();
        //or more specific
       if ($location.$$url == '/specific/path') {
         $element.focus();
       }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I know that everyone is saying that we shouldn't apply focus from within a controller but let me explain my problem here... I have a dataservice which return a JSON object and from within that result object, there's an information which tells me if something is wrong in my form, if so I will then focus on that specified field. So basically this is saying, from within controller, call a dataservice and from the response, we continue or we focus on field and ask user to make a correction. I don't see other ways of doing this outside of the controller.

Comment: I gave an example of my form/controller in my question. You might understand more of what I want to focus a field from within the controller

Comment: So you're implementing form validator-like progress in your controller. basically, you're working with AngularJS to implement MVC method on your app. in MVC the controller's target is to bind data recieved from data layer (Model) to View, so I think any kind of view manipulation in controller is a wrong idea. Possibly you could pin a flag on scope, and on $scope.$watch check for it instead of $location.$$url in my response.

Answer (score 1):

I've made this directive:

```
app.directive('rfocus',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var fooName = 'setFocus' + $attrs.rfocus; 
            $scope[fooName] = function(){
                $element.focus();                
            } 
        },
    }    
});
```

It adds to controller's `$scope` function to set focus on element. Name of the function is based on value given in attribute.

Using: `<input type="text" rfocus="Input1"/>` will create function `setFocusInput1()` which you can use in your controller.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/2PJMQ/

Comment: But again that equals to writing something in my HTML code, I would rather not... how would I do it directly in the Controller? Without code in the HTML, wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: How do you want to select specific element without using additional attributes? You can't set focus to all inputs at the same time - you have to determine which one should be focused. You can use `id` attribute for that and then select an input with jQuery (but "it's not angular way"), or create directive like above.

Comment: I only want to focus on 1 element, let say I want to focus on Input12, then in jQuery I would simply write this: `$('input12').focus();`, I could do it in my controller, actually that is what I'm doing now, but how would I do it the Angular way? Without writing code in HTML, If I have 20 inputs, I don't want to have to write 20 times something on each inputs. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started to learn Angular, too, but hopefully I can provide you a different way of approaching this.

I've been using some basic jQuery to focus, too, so in that regard, I can't really help you. However, with regard to calling a directive within a controller, I can't find any articles that say "yes, you can", or "no, you can't". I know that you can declare a controller within a directive, though, so you miiiiight be able to do something like this:

```
.directive('ngxFocus', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: //do your controller stuff here
}])
```

Comment: Hmm ok but that doesn't help me to call it within my controller... And the restrict to 'A', I believe it is the default, so that is why I don't need to define it. My directive works as I want inside my HTML, but I'm looking into how to do it via the controller, not via HTML(DOM). There is a big different between the 2..

Comment: Well, element focusing requires some sort of DOM manipulation, right? If that's the case, then you'll have to go with the directive, since controllers shouldn't be used for DOM manipulation.

Btw, you're right about restrict defaulting to 'A', seems like I need to read the documentation more thoroughly

Comment: That is correct to some extense, but I'm inside a controller function and I want to focus on another element from within that function (inside the controller), then... I'm not talking about a page load, I'm talking about a function that needs to focus on unknown element, only known inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but here's an other approach, where you set to true a variable in the controller, and that's this action that set the focus to your element.

Try this:

```
myAngularModule.directive('goFocus', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.goFocus, function (newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    }, 100);
                }
            });
            element.bind("blur", function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.goFocus + "=false");
                }, 10);
            });
            element.bind("focus", function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.goFocus + "=true");
                }, 10);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

In HTML template:

```
<input go-focus="focusvar1" type="text" ng-model="mytext1" />
<input go-focus="focusvar2" type="text" ng-model="mytext2" />
<input go-focus="focusvar3" type="text" ng-model="mytext3" />
<button ng-click="doFocus()">OK</button>
```

In javascript angular controller:

```
myAngularModule.controller('myController', function () {
    var self = this;

    self.doFocus = function () {
        // do some logic and focus your field
        self.focusvar2 = true;
    };
});
```